# What should I do when I find an error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting the following error in my stack trace in Android Studio:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start find usages from under write action. Please consider Application.invokeLater() it instead.

Does anyone know where I should start to look in my code to find exactly what part of my code is causing this to happen?

What should I do if I encounter this error.  There is an option to submit it to Google, but in meantime then my projects get disturbed.  I searched about this but didn't get a suitable answer.

NOTE: Since getting this error, I have faced unexpected behaviors in my android project.   I had faced this issue several times in other projects too, where I got issues like unexpected and unintentional opening of activities.  In one project of mine I got the consequences from this error as my "Preview" section in XML was not showing.

Please help, ask me if some more info if necessary.

FULL STACK TRACE:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start find usages from under
>   write action. Please consider Application.invokeLater() it instead.
>     at
>   com.intellij.usages.impl.UsageViewManagerImpl.doSearchAndShow(UsageViewManagerImpl.java:132)
>     at
>   com.intellij.usages.impl.UsageViewManagerImpl.searchAndShowUsages(UsageViewManagerImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.nullable.NullableStuffInspection$NavigateToNullLiteralArguments.invoke(NullableStuffInspection.java:144)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.applyFix(LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.java:102)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.applyFix(LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.java:92)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.applyFix(LocalQuickFixOnPsiElement.java:26)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.QuickFixWrapper.invoke(QuickFixWrapper.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.IntentionActionWithTextCaching$MyIntentionAction.invoke(IntentionActionWithTextCaching.java:181)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.ShowIntentionActionsHandler.lambda$invokeIntention$3(ShowIntentionActionsHandler.java:209)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.run(WriteAction.java:91)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.ShowIntentionActionsHandler.invokeIntention(ShowIntentionActionsHandler.java:211)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.ShowIntentionActionsHandler.lambda$null$1(ShowIntentionActionsHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.ShowIntentionActionsHandler.lambda$chooseActionAndInvoke$2(ShowIntentionActionsHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.ShowIntentionActionsHandler.chooseActionAndInvoke(ShowIntentionActionsHandler.java:184)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.IntentionListStep.lambda$applyAction$1(IntentionListStep.java:293)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.lambda$null$7(AbstractPopup.java:1431)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Do you use a version control system such as git?  If so, you could rollback to a previous commit that was known to work and reapply your changes until you encounter the error.  If the known commit doesn't work anymore, then you could reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: Ok , So from now onwards I will keep in mind to upload my projects in git but for now what should I do as I didn't had commited my changes to git / Then what should I do to go back and see whats the problem. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: Had you made any of your project's files read-only on disk?  I'm asking because it looks like that error is from `isWriteAccessAllowed()` returning false in https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/usageView/src/com/intellij/usages/impl/UsageViewManagerImpl.java

Comment: No I haven't made any of them as read-only on disk.

Comment: Then I would probably restart with a basic "hello world" project in a different folder and add your code to it part by part until you can reproduce the problem.  That will isolate the area of code that's causing the problem and it may be easier to investigate then.  Oh, and introduce a version control system like git as part of this.